# Cordova plugin development workflow

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

When building an Hybrid iOS Cordova application (relying on Cordova CLI) I stumbled the need to build a custom plugin.

My workflow was the following:

1. I scaffolded my Cordova plugin outside my Hybrid Application
   directory.
2. Code it blindly (in Vim) and push to GitHub.
3. Use `cordova plugin rm` and `cordova plugin add` to reinstall the plugin.
4. Test.
5. Repeat from step 2.

I deployed the plugin successfully in the product, however this process of coding Objective C blindly with Vim and doing a whole push to GitHub just to test it in my project feels awkward, however I couldn't find any information on the internet about a better workflow.

Ideally, this is the workflow I'd expect:

1. Scaffold my plugin inside my application directory (maybe in plugins/ or in my custom src/) and publish when I'm ready to do so (or not publish closed-source plugins at all).
2. Code the plugin using XCode.
3. Reinstall the plugin from the local filesystem, this totally avoiding a separate repo/push.
4. Test and iterate from step 2.

Is this workflow achievable?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following workflow:

1. have the plugin in a specific directory within the project
2. have a [grunt](http://gruntjs.com) task that watches for changes in the above directory that copies the relevant files to the plugins directory and runs `cordova prepare` right after the copy step is complete
3. edite and test...

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I've used the same approach, with a twist:

#### Step 1:

I've coded the boilerplate part of the plugin using Sublime Text (vim works as well :) )

#### Step 2:

```
cordova plugin add --link ../path_to_my_plugin
```

#### Step 3:

I can add the platforms/android to Android Studio (you should be able to do the same with platforms/ios)

#### Step 4:

Any changes to the native part are reflected in the original sources (because of the --link parameter), any changes needed to the js part of the plugin I can edit directly in the app directory itself

#### Step 5:

Commit and push the files in your original plugin directory

If you need to reconfigure some part of the boilerplate (plugin.xml configurations), I've just:

```
cordova plugin remove <plugin-name>
```

And then resumed from step 2